# Jquery to check height and add class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to check which div has bigger height and than place a class inside the one that is greater.

I have this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var sideNavMenu = $(".col-md-3").height();
    var mainColumn = $(".col-md-9").height();

    if (sideNavMenu > mainColumn)
    {
        $(".col-md-3").addClass('dotRight');
    }
    else
    {
        $(".col-md-9").addClass('dotLeft');
    }

});
```

The goal here is to check if sideNavMenu is greater than mainColumn than place dotRight on its div tag.

If the mainColumn is greater, then place dotLeft on its div tag.

But its not working.

Any suggestion how to change/improve it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you're trying to make a style that just adds a dotted border between your left and right columns, you could probably use an absolutely positioned pseudo element instead

Comment: try doing a `console.log(sideNavMenu + " "+ mainColumn);` to check if you are getting the heights properly

Comment: what's not working? the class is not added, or it is but you don't get the expected look?

Comment: The class is not added

Comment: run console.log and gives me error: `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reference these by IDs and not classes, since there can be multiple elements with these class names on the page. There **should** only be one with each ID.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var sideNavMenu = $("#sidebar").height();
  var mainColumn = $("#main").height();

  if (sideNavMenu > mainColumn) {
    $("#sidebar").addClass('dotRight');
  }  else {
    $(".#main").addClass('dotLeft');
  }
});
```

Of course, you need to add the id's to your `<div>`s respectively.

The [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/height/) say:

> Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements or set the height of every matched element.

But, I was just playing with it in jsfiddle and it seems to return an **object** containing the height of the first element.

http://jsfiddle.net/wwx2m/2/

Which means you should be able to do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var sideNavMenu = $(".col-md-3").height();
  var mainColumn = $(".col-md-9").height();

  if (JSON.stringify(sideNavMenu) > JSON.stringify(mainColumn)) {
    $(".col-md-3").addClass('dotRight');
  } else {
    $(".col-md-9").addClass('dotLeft');
  }
});
```

But the first way I said is preferred. This is not stable, since there can be more objects introduced with the same class. The only reason I'm even mentioning it is to explain why you were having problems with your original code. :)

http://jsfiddle.net/wwx2m/4/

Comment: I still getting this error ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @KleberBH That means your jQuery library is not properly loaded.

Comment: Ok fixed it, I just placed the script tag after the jquery library script and worked fine.

Comment: @KleberBH That can be an issue. Personally, I always load jquery right after the title in the header and make sure it's the very first thing loaded. `<header><title>This Site</title><script src="jquery.js"></script>....`

Answer (score 0):

I put the jsfiddle together for you

```
<html>
<div class='col-md-3'>
</div>
<div class='col-md-9'>
</div>


<script>
var sideNavMenu = $(".col-md-3").height();
var mainColumn = $(".col-md-9").height();



if (sideNavMenu > mainColumn){
    $(".col-md-3").addClass('dotRight');
}
else{
    $(".col-md-9").addClass('dotLeft');
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/je7u9/)

[updated jsFiddle with Animation](http://jsfiddle.net/je7u9/2/)